# copy data from one HDFS directory to another continuously

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, rsync

I have a directory in hdfs which gets files populated every 2 days. I want to copy all the files in this directory to another in such a way that if a new file comes in today, I want the file to be copied to the duplicate directory.

How can we do that in Hdfs.

I know we can do that in linux using rsync. Is there any method like this in Hdfs as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no file sync methods available with HDFS. You have to either do `hdfs dfs -cp` or `hadoop distcp` manually or through any scheduler (`cron`).

If the number of files are more, `distcp` is preferred.

```
hadoop distcp -update <src_dir> <dest_dir>
```

The `-update` flag would overwrite if source and destination differ in size, blocksize, or checksum.

Comment: `distcp` `-update` as you say overwrites the whole directory. Is there a way to just check if there are only changes and if there are changes then update only those changes

Comment: No, it overwrites only the changes. If the source has 10 files and the destination already has 5 of it, distcp will write only the remaining 5 to the destination. This update flag would check if there are any updates in those already existing 5 files as well, if there are they will be overwritten else skipped.